# How to create a Tree view with a main root not selectable and children selectable in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code:

```
var items = new TreeViewItem();
items.Header = "all Items";
items.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "a" });
items.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "b" });
items.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = "c" });
```

But "all items" header is selectable.

How can I prevent the header to be selectable?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "selectable"? The highlight or the fact that is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
 <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem Header="all items" Focusable="False" >
            <TreeViewItem  Header="a"/>
            <TreeViewItem  Header="b"/>
            <TreeViewItem  Header="c"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
  </TreeView>
```

or if you want the code behind:

```
        TreeView t = new TreeView();
        TreeViewItem root = new TreeViewItem();
        root.Header = "all items";
        root.Focusable = false;
        TreeViewItem t1 = new TreeViewItem();
        root.Header = "a";
        TreeViewItem t2 = new TreeViewItem();
        root.Header = "b";
        TreeViewItem t3 = new TreeViewItem();
        root.Header = "c";
        root.Items.Add(t1);
        root.Items.Add(t2);
        root.Items.Add(t3);
        t.Items.Add(root);
```